Variations of Dawson's function
I am studying Dawson's function : $\displaystyle F : x \mapsto e^{-x^2}\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$.
I would like to prove that $F$ attains a maximum at a certain value $x_0 \in (0,1)$, and is increasing over $[0,x_0]$ and decreasing over $[x_0, +\infty)$.
The only thing I managed to prove about this function is that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} F(x)=0$, which gives the existence of a maximum over $[0,+\infty)$, but does not help to determine the variations of $F$.
I also know that $F$ is solution of the differential equation $y'+2xy=1$, but I cannot see how it could help.
So the question is : how to determine the variations of $F$ ? (and bonus : how to prove that $x_0 <1$ ?)

EDIT : Thanks to @NinadMunshi's answer, I understand now why there exists $x_0 \in (0,1)$ such that $F'(x_0)=0$.
But I still don't understand how to prove that $x_0$ is the only root of $F'$ over $[0,+\infty)$ (which would solve my initial question) Does anybody know how to tackle this question ?

Let $x \geq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
2x F(x)
&= 2x e^{-x^2} \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= e^{-x^2} \int_{0}^{1} 2x^2 e^{x^2 s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s \tag{$t = xs$} \\
&= e^{-x^2} \biggl( \biggl[ \frac{e^{x^2 s^2} - 1}{s} \biggr]_{s=0}^{s=1} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{x^2s^2} - 1}{s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s \biggr) \\
&= 1 - e^{-x^2} + e^{-x^2} G(x),
\end{align*}
where $G(x)$ is defined by
$$ G(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{x^2s^2} - 1}{s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$
So it follows that
\begin{align*}
F'(x)
= 1 - 2x F(x)
= e^{-x^2}( 1 - G(x) ).
\end{align*}
However, it is clear that $G(0) = 0$ and $G(x)$ is strictly increasing on $x \geq 0$ with $G(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. So, there exists a unique positive solution $x = x_0$ of the equation
$$ G(x) = 1, $$
and we have
$$ \begin{cases}
F'(x) > 0 \iff x < x_0, \\
F'(x) = 0 \iff x = x_0, \\
F'(x) < 0 \iff x > x_0.
\end{cases} $$
This proves that $F(x)$ attains a unique maximum on $[0, \infty)$.

Addendum. Using the inequality $e^x > 1 + x$ for $x > 0$, we know that
$$ G(1) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{s^2} - 1}{s^2} \, \mathrm{d}s > \int_{0}^{1} \, \mathrm{d}s = 1. $$
This implies $x_0 < 1$ as required.

Thank you very much, that is perfect !

Hint (too long for a comment)
There are two points to recall
$$F(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{\Gamma  \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$ and
$$F'(x)=1-2 x F(x)=\sqrt{\pi }\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{x^{2 n}}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ Build the $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ of $F'(x)$ such as
$$P_2=\frac {1-\frac{10 }{7}x^2+\frac{32
   }{105}x^4 }{1+\frac{4 }{7}x^2+\frac{4}{35}x^4 }$$ To give an idea of the accuracy, compute numerically the infinite norm
$$\Phi_2=\int_0^1 \Big(F'(x)-P_2 \Big)^2\,dx=4.22213\times 10^{-7}$$
If you are ready to work with cubic equations in $x^2$
$$\Phi_3=\int_0^1 \Big(F'(x)-P_3 \Big)^2\,dx=2.14162\times 10^{-11}$$ that is to say that you can have a good approximation of $x_*$ such that $F'(x_*)=0$.
Yous could do the same kind of work with
$$F''(x)=2\left(2 x^2-1\right) F(x)-2 x$$ and find the inflection point.

Thanks for the answer ! However, I can't understand why $F'$ should have an unique root over $(0,+\infty)$. Am I missing something obvious ?

From your differential equation we know that the maximum occurs when $2xy=1$. On the interval $[0,1]$ we have that
$$0\cdot F(0) = 0$$
$$2\cdot F(1) = \frac{2}{e}\int_0^1 e^{t^2}dt > 1$$
So the solution where it equals $1$ must exist on the interval by intermediate value theorem.

Thanks for the answer. However, if I undestand it correctly, it only proves that the derivative of $F$ vanishes at a certain point of the interval $(0,1)$. My question was rather about the global variations of $F$ over $(0,+\infty)$. Do you know how to prove that $F$ is increasing and then decreasing on this interval ?

@Henry intermediate value theorem still applies. When you know the only root of $y'$ occurs at a single point, what can you say about the sign of $y'$ when $x>x_0$? $x<x_0$?

Precisely, I don't know why $y'$ has an only root over $(0,+\infty)$... Am I missing something obvious ?
